# Priority queue of pairs in reverse order

Tags: c++, priority-queue

I'm wanting to do something like this:

```
priority_queue< pair<int, int>, vector<int>, greater<int> > Q;
```

This works fine if the type I'm comparing is `int`, i.e.:

```
priority_queue< int, vector<int>, greater<int> > Q;
```

however, obviously with the `pair<int, int>`, there is no way of comparing the pairs in the queue with the standard `>`. I was wondering what I should do? How would I implement an overloaded `>` or is there another way I can create a priority queue of pairs with the smallest `pair.second` being at the top of the queue?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
typedef pair<int, int> P;
priority_queue< P, vector<P>, greater<P> > Q;
```

This will give the reverse ordering of the normal `operator<` for `pair<int, int>`, which will start with the smallest `first` tie-broken with smallest `second`.

If you want to sort by smallest `second` first and `first` second (!) then you'll need a new sorting functor:

```
struct Order
{
    bool operator()(P const& a, P const& b) const
    {
        return a.second < b.second || a.second == b.second && a.first < b.first;
    }
}
```

Then use:

```
priority_queue< P, vector<P>, Order > Q;
```

Comment: oops deleted comment after I saw your edit. I asked: "Is there a way to specify which pair element is being compared?".

Answer (score 0):

You should create your own domain class rather than using `pair<int, int>` here, as far as I can see. Then  you can overload `>` as you like.